# How can I join two MySQL Tables on dates within a few days of each other?

Tags: mysql, join

Here's the situation: I'm attempting to JOIN two MySQL Tables, each of which include logs of transactions for cruise sailings. Both tables would include fields such as: First name, Last name, Amount, Transaction Date, Cruise Line, Ship, and Sailing Date.

I'm trying to determine which transaction on each table can be affirmatively matched to another for bookkeeping purposes. So far this is a fairly simple matter, using an INNER JOIN ON firstname, lastname, amount, cruiseline, ship, sailingdate... but as for Transaction Date, I'm looking for a range, where the two dates are within a couple days of each other. This is because it's possible for a transaction to have been entered by a human into one database a day or two after the other database.

I need some way in MySQL to be able to match transactions for which the transaction date on one table occurs +/- 2 days of the other, and still matches all the other fields above I listed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something like `JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.transaction_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(t.transaction_date, INTERVAL -2 DAY)` should work, but without more details (table names, table schemas, example data) we likely can't provide a much more concrete answer. Note this query will be slooooow because it can't `JOIN` on indexed columns due to the `DATE_ADD` functions. Though arguably JOINing on a transaction_date field is probably not the best idea, because presumably multiple transactions could happen on the same day?

Comment: Yeah, this particular situation isn't quite an exact science (Table of 1200 entries and I've already positively matched like 500). I'm not expecting multiple transactions to occur on the same day to the same person, in the same amount, for the same sailing, and if they do, I can deal with them by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) which returns the difference of 2 dates in days in the `ON` clause:

```
ON ..... AND ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.SailingDate, t2.SailingDate)) <= 2
```